# How to Develop a User Score Function in Javascript Quiz

Tags: javascript, html, function

I am currently trying to build a user score function for a javascript quiz and I can't seem to figure out how to 1) pull the answer selected based on a click event and 2) determine whether that scrore is true or false. Based on their answer, I want it to build it into a score board. And then post the results at the end of the quiz.

I've tried adding a target but can't seem to even get that to log. I have a check answer function where it moves to the next question but I also want that click event to tally up a score.

**Code:**

```js
var startQuizBtn = document.getElementById("start-quiz");

// start quiz button with a fuction to trigger the quiz questions (showQuestons())
startQuizBtn.onclick = function() {
  console.log('button click')
  showQuestions(), setTime();
};

console.log(setTime);

var timeEl = document.querySelector(".time");

var resultsEl = document.getElementById("results");

var secondsLeft = 15;
// function that starts timer when you click start quiz
function setTime() {
  // Sets interval in variable
  var timerInterval = setInterval(function() {
    secondsLeft--;
    timeEl.textContent = secondsLeft;

    if (secondsLeft === 0) {
      // Stops execution of action at set interval
      clearInterval(timerInterval);
      // Calls function to create and append results of quiz
      userScore();
    }

  }, 1000);
}


// the questions that will be asked during the quiz 
var myQuestions = [{
    question: "Javascript is an _______ language?",
    answers: ["Object-Oriented", "Object-Based", "Procedural", "None of the above"],
  },
  {
    question: "Which of the following keywords is used to define a variable in Javascript?",
    answers: ["var", "bar", "jar", "bob"],
  },
  {
    question: "Which of the following methods is used to access HTML elements using Javascript?",
    answers: ["targetElement", "thatOneElement", "getElementById", "idElement"],
  },
];

var questionIndex = 0

console.log(myQuestions[questionIndex])
console.log(myQuestions[questionIndex].question)

// main function to show quiz question in a sequential order after clicking start quiz 
function showQuestions() {

  startQuizBtn.style.display = "none";

  var quizAnswers = document.getElementById("answers");

  var questionTitle = myQuestions[questionIndex].question

  var questionh3 = document.getElementById("questions")

  questionh3.textContent = questionTitle
  quizAnswers.textContent = ""

  myQuestions[questionIndex].answers.forEach(function(q) {

    // takes answers and turns them into buttons below questions
    var ul = document.getElementById("answers");
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    var answerBtn = document.createElement("button");
    li.appendChild(answerBtn);
    ul.appendChild(li)
    // button styling
    answerBtn.textContent = q
    answerBtn.style.padding = "10px"
    li.style.listStyle = "none"
    li.style.marginTop = "5px"
    li.style.marginBottom = "5px"


    quizAnswers.appendChild(answerBtn)

    answerBtn.addEventListener("click", checkAnswer)
    answerBtn.addEventListener("click", userScore)

    console.log(q)
  })
}

var scoreCounter = 0;
var answerIndex = 0;

function userScore(e) {

  var selectedAnswer =
    console.log(selectedAnswer)

  var correct = myQuestions.answers
  if (selectedAnswer === correct) {
    scoreCounter = scoreCounter + 1;
  }
}

function checkAnswer() {
  questionIndex++
  showQuestions()
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>
    <h1>Code Quiz Challenge</h1>
    <p id="quiz-rules">Welcome to the Javascript fundamentals quiz! Answer the questions to test your Javascript knowledge. This quiz does have a time limit. If you answer the question incorrectly, you will be penalized with ten seconds off your timer. To begin the quiz,
      select Start Quiz below. </p>
  </header>
  <div id=quiz-container>
    <div id="start-button-container">
      <button id="start-quiz">Start Quiz</button>
    </div>
    <h2 class="time">
      </h1>
      <h3 id="questions"></h3>
      <ul id="answers"></ul>
      <div id="score"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: `console.log(setTime);` is not very useful, since `setTime` is a function.

Comment: The objects in the `questions` array need to indicate which is the correct answer. E.g. `correctId: 2` to indicate that element 2 of `answers` is correct.

Comment: `var selectedAnswer = console.log(selectedAnswer)` makes little sense. You're using the variable when initializing itself, and `console.log()` doesn't return anything.

Comment: When you create the answer buttons, you can put the array index in a property, e.g. `answerBtn.dataset.id = index;`. Then when the user clicks on the answer button, you can compare this with `questions[questionIndex].correctId`